# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type inside own library

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have several struct: edge, vertex, graph in my library.
I want to hide body of that structs from user (user have to use API), so in header file (eg. edge.h) I've just put:

```
typedef struct edge edge_t;
```

And definition of edge struct is in edge.c

```
struct edge {...};
```

That works fine, but I want don't want to hide struct's body from my own code. I want to use in edge.c:

```
vertex_t v;
v.some_attribute = x;
```

Now I get dereferencing pointer to incomplete type errors, is it possible to fix that?
Is there any other option that use accessors (like user) for all struct elements?

Comment: If the struct's structure is known in your library, it's no incomplete type. Have a header used only in your library that defines the struct and a public header that exports only the abstract type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use the structure from other source files, they need the complete definition of the structure. So the solution is to put `struct edge { /* ... */ }` in the header file as well, and include the header whenever you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Joachim Pileborg is correct.

The compiler needs to know the size of the structure to be able to work with it. The only way you can prevent this is by forcing the user to use pointers.

`typedef struct edge *edge_t;`

The compiler knows the size of the pointer, thus it knows how much space it needs to allocate for it.

Comment: `typedef` pointers can lead to all sorts of problems when `malloc` is involved. People forget that the `typedef` is a pointer. Better to be explicit in the code

Comment: At least suffix a typedef'ed pointer to make it clear, `typedef struct edge *edge_ptr;` would be less likely to be confused.